# handling returned data from web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have created the following [web service](http://www.syncro-it.co.uk/service/server.php?wsdl)

I have created a dummy client in a c# blank web application. using the following I add data to the service -

```
www.SyncroWebService ws = new www.SyncroWebService();

ws.addNewProduct(new www.AddProductRequest(){
CorrelationId = "Test",
StoreId = 1,
StorePassword = "password",
Products = new www.Product[]
{
new www.Product() { categoryName = "Cat_Rory", departmentName = "Dept_Rory", productName = "Product_Rory", productPrice = 100, productId = 1},
new www.Product() { categoryName = "Cat_Test", departmentName = "Dept_Test", productName = "Product_Test", productPrice = 100, productId = 2}
}
});
```

The method in the web service for AddProductrequest will then add this data to DB and return the ProductId of each "Product" added with a message saying whether it was added or not.

How can I output the returned data in the client to say a textbox? just So I know the returned data is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returned data could be, for example, a class named `MyResponse`

```
class MyResponse
{
    int Result {get; set;}
    List<int> Ids {get; set;}

    public MyResponse() 
    {
        Result = 0;
        Ids = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

So you could try:

```
MyResponse resp = ws.addNewProduct(new www.AddProductReque(...
if (resp.Result == 0) 
{
    string text = String.Join(";", resp.Ids);
    // Do what you please here
}
```